# Get innerHTML from XMLHttpResponse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that will get a value from a current page, then use that information to go to another page and pull a specific element from the html response. I can get the html response fine, but I'm unable to parse the html response to get the specific element.

content.js

```
function getTicketInfo(){
    var ticketURI = document.getElementById("p3_lkid").value;
    var ticketNumber = document.getElementById("p3_lkold").value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET',"remotePage.html",true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            function handleResponse(xhr)
        }
    }

    xhr.send();
}

function handleResponse(xhr){
    var contactElement = xhr.getElementById("CF00N80000005MAX6_ileinner");
    alert(contactElement.clildNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

remotePage.html

```
<html>
    <div id="CF00N80000005MAX6_ileinner">
        <a href="/0033400001pt8Ox" id="lookup0033400001pt8Ox00N80000005MAX6">Text I need!</a>
    </div>
</html>
```

How can I get this value from the external page? Is there a better way to request this information?

Comment: You could try passing it as a parameter value in the GET address if that's something you can do. It will be visible though.

Answer (score 0):

Your XHR response is a string, and not a DOM.
With jQuery you'll be able to convert it to a DOM, and query it.

```
function handleResponse(xhr){
    $(xhr.response).find('#CF00N80000005MAX6_ileinner')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as not parsing the HTML response to a DOM object. According to MDN, this is how you parse XML (Or HTML, and with Vanilla JavaScript):

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
```

`var doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr, "text/xml");`

And then using the new DOM Object `doc` for accessing elements.

```
var contactElement = doc.getElementById("CF00N80000005MAX6_ileinner");
alert(contactElement.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

I also noticed you spelled `childNodes` wrong, but that isn't the main problem.